# Android Build failed with duplicate class error

Tags: android

I'm getting duplicate class error when building my application.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Program type already present: javax.annotation.Nonnegative$Checker
```

I would like to track down `javax.annotation.Nonnegative$Checker` and which libraries are using it. Please guide me how to track duplicate classes in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by upgrading dagger version from 2.10 to 2.15. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: if you find your solution, then you can also accept your answer. So others can get it helpful